# Firestore: Checking snapshot.exists always returns false even though there are documents in the collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my Firestore setup. As you can see, there are documents in this collection.
[image]

[image]

This is my code to get a Snapshot of the documents in the collection. It is always returning false. Can someone help me figure out how to fix it?

```
firebase.firestore().collection("chatMessages").doc("chatMessages").collection(chatId).get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists) { // <- always returning false
      console.log("snapshot exists");
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a query there is no `.exists` property -- that's a property of a `DocumentSnapshot` not a `QuerySnapshot`. I think you want [empty](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty) instead:

```
if (!snapshot.empty) {
  console.log('query returned results');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this for more details - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data